# Confusion about endomorphism in two different bases

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B=(1,X,X^2)$ and $B'=(P_1,P_2,P_3)$ be two bases of $\mathbb R_2[X]$ where $P_1=X^2+1$, $P_2=X+1$ and $P_3=2X^2-X$. The transformation matrix $P$ from $B'$ to $B$ is \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & -1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 2
\end{array}
with inverse $P^{-1}$ given by 
\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & -2 & -1 \\ 
-1 & 2 & 1 \\ 
-1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}

Let $\theta$ the endomorphism that sends a polynomial $P\in \mathbb R_2[X]$ to $XP'$ where $P'$ is the differential polynomial.

Now let $Q=X^2-X+2$ which in coordinates is $Q=(2,-1,1)_{B}$ . By transforamtion matrix $Q=(5,-3,-2)_{B'}$. the matrix of $\theta$ with respect to $B$ is
\begin{array}{ccc}
0& 0& 0\\ 
0& 1& 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 2
\end{array} 
and using the transformation matrix, we find that the matrix of $\theta$ with respect to $B'$ is 
\begin{array}{ccc}
4 & 2 & 2\\ 
-2 & 0 & 2 \\ 
-2 & -1 & -1
\end{array}
Now here is my confusion: $\theta(Q)=XQ'=X(2X-1)=2X^2-X=P_3$
But to find the image of $Q$ by $\theta$ using the matrix of $\theta$ in the basis of $B'$
I find 
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
4 & 2 & 2\\ 
-2 & 0 & 2 \\ 
-2 & -1 & -1
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 
5 \\
-3 \\
-2
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 
10\\
-6\\
-5
\end{pmatrix}$$
But $10P_1-6P_2-5P_3=-X+4$ so how can we find that $\theta(Q)=2X^2-X$ and also $\theta(Q)=-X+4$ should'nt the result be the same ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think your differentiation matrix for $\theta$ is wrong. The one and two should be shifted one space to the north-west.

Comment: I think my computations are correct, but the problem is that why we can have two different results, it must be some explanation for this. Infact if they were the same we would have $10P_1-6P_2-5P_3=P_3$ which is impossible since they form a basis. But why they are different!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just some confusion regarding the transformation matrices. It helps to use a decent notation system. So the $B'$-to-$B$ change of basis matrix can be written Mtx$_{B,B'}(\boldsymbol \iota)$. It might seem counterintuitive to write $B'$ second and $B$ first, but it makes sense when you think of multiplication by this matrix on the left - the vector on the right is in $B'$ coordinates and is changed to $B$ coordinates. So when multiplying with this matrix you must always make sure that a vector in $B'$ coordinates is next to the subscript $B'$: eg Mtx$_{B,B'}(\boldsymbol \iota)v_{B'}$

So now have a look at the equation: \begin{equation}\text{Mtx}_{B',B'}(\boldsymbol \theta)=\text{Mtx}_{B',B}(\boldsymbol \iota)\text{Mtx}_{B,B}(\boldsymbol \theta)\text{Mtx}_{B,B'}(\boldsymbol \iota). \end{equation}
So the change of basis matrix notation must be "compatible" with the matrix representation notation - you must have $B$ subscripts next to $B$ subscripts, etc.

So in your question: $P=$ Mtx$_{B,B'}(\boldsymbol \iota)$, $P^{-1}=$ Mtx$_{B',B}(\boldsymbol \iota)$ and the matrix representative of $\boldsymbol \theta$ with respect to the $B$ basis is Mtx$_{B,B}(\boldsymbol \theta)$. So we must have \begin{equation}\text{Mtx}_{B',B'}(\boldsymbol \theta)=P^{-1}\text{Mtx}_{B,B}(\boldsymbol \theta)P=\begin{bmatrix}-2& -2& -2\\2& 2& 2\\2& 1& 3\end{bmatrix}. \end{equation}